# "Importation" => "Import"

Tags: traduction

Comment faire pour faire changer la traduction de "to import" imposée notamment par les correcteurs orthographiques des logiciels (mais aussi dans les dictionnaires papier de papi), de manière à ce qu'ils ne mettent pas l'horrible mot "importation" mais le mot "import" à la place ?

Ou plus largement, comment faire pour faire accepter dans le dictionnaire officiel de la langue française, que le mot "import" a remplacé le mot "importation" dans la signification de l'action d'apporter des éléments dans un système. Importation reste un mot intéressant pour qualifier les items rapportés dans un système (un pays par ex: "nos importations records ont contribué au déficit de notre balance commerciale"). Mais il n'est plus utilisé pour qualifier l'action d'importer. On dit "j'importe" et non "j'importation". L'action d'importer se doit d'être "Import" et non "Importation".

Combien de temps et qui va se charger de mettre à jour nos dictionnaires ?

Je me base sur le fait que le Français est une langue vivante, et qu'il n'est pas question de la rendre "morte" en la codant en dur sur différents supports.
Un mot qui est moche se doit d'être remplacé par un mot qui est beau.

"Importation" est ridiculement et inutilement long. Et ne donne pas plus d'information qu'import.

Un import, de l'export.
Une importation, de l'exportation.
Pourquoi pas une importationne et de l'exportationne pendant qu'on y est ?

Exemple:

[image]

Comment: "Import" is certainly shorter, but to the extent that [this answer on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/49810/import-vs-importance/148653#148653) is correct about the meaning of "Ça n'a pas d'import" in French couldn't "erreur d'import" be ambiguous and perhaps lead to some people misinterpreting it to mean "an important error," as opposed to "an unimportant error" (and not as opposed to "an export error," as intended)?

Comment: @PapaPoule *Import* is never used as an abbreviation of *important* in France French. It is used as an abbreviation of *importation* but almost exclusively in relation with export (*import-export*). In the computing jargon, *import* is a synonym of *importation* but the latter pose no problem. *Erreur d'importation* is just fine.

Comment: Il n'y a pas de vraie question. La configuration de « logiciels » n'est de toute façon pas du ressort de ce site.

Comment: Ce n'est pas une question de configuration "de logiciels". C'est une question d'évolution de la langue que les logiciels avec leurs correcteurs orthographiques imposent bien plus qu'un dictionnaire, bloquant par la l'évolution normale de la langue vivante. Le logiciel est ici mis en exergue pour démontrer le bloquage provoqué par ces dictionnaires sur cette évolution, qui mènera sans aucun doute à une révolution humaine. Vous êtes censés être des spécialistes de la langue, mais vous préférez la censure. Continuez sur votre lancée, n'ouvrez surtout pas votre esprit et votre imagination.

Comment: Voici +1 pour vous éviter de passer sous le seuil d'entrée. J'espère que vous trouverez une manière de formuler une Q. sur la langue, vu votre  intérêt... Par exemple : « En informatique, pour désigner [ définition ], _import_ et _importation_ sont-ils tous les deux aussi usuels ; le premier est-il prononcé "à la française", est-ce deux emprunts ou le premier suffixé ; si leur sens était identique, qu'est-ce qu'ajouterait le suffixe en _-tion_ ; y a-t-il des types de phrases où l'un ajouterait qqc, qu'en est-il avec _erreur de_ ; _l'importation (qui est) faite_ est-ce redondant ? » etc. Merci!

Comment: Non, ce n'est pas une question. C'est une complainte, et tous les dictionnaires du monde ne sont pas obligés de s'accorder sur votre goût.

Comment: Si vous n'utilisez pas ce mot, pourquoi intervenir de la sorte ? Ce n'est pas une complainte, c'est un fait.

Comment: « Erreur lors de l'import » ou « Erreur d'importation », but not « Erreur d'import ». At least, as a developer, that's what I would use. Also, terms in Computers may be different from the one used in everyday.  They have separate lives.

Answer (score 1):

Il faut se connecter sur ton compte Google puis aller dans le site de Google traduction et lorsque tu fait la traduction tu cliques sur proposer une autre traduction.

Comment: Je voulais dire pas pour mes traductions, mais pour les traductions francaises des logiciels google et microsoft par ex. Ca m'horripile ce terme partout.